# Cell validation with dropdown

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How to validate data in cells with dropdown for preventing enter same values in two neighbour cells?
[Spreadsheet test link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/199dCiVckmh2pEpGgc7QNH9i_rCChYLhaxb35wMyrPao/edit?usp=sharing)
For my experience it's impossible to enter custom `=myFunction()` in the cell with data validation.

Comment: so you want the list of the dropdown to only contain non-adjacent values?

Comment: You could use the dropdown on the cell and an onEdit trigger to check against the neighbor cells.

Comment: @RobinGertenbach yes

Comment: @JordanRhea `onEdit` as a function inside each cell?

Comment: onEdit is a function you can write inside the script editor.https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#onedit